# Grouping lines in csv file in Java

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and i have to parse a `.csv` file. The file contains in each line the ID of a student, the ID of the subject they passed and the grade they passed the subject.
For example:

```
Student ID,Subject ID,Grade
1,A1-102,7
1,A1-103,6
1,A1-104,5
1,A1-108,9
2,A1-101,5
2,A1-105,7
```

I need to count the number of lessons a student has passed in a way similar to `SQL's` `GROUP BY` E.g: `SELECT count(*) FROM STUDENTS GROUP BY Student_ID;` Assuming the csv file is opened and ready to be read, is there a way to group multiple entries for one student?

My code:

```
csvFile = "C:\\Myfile.csv";

             try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
              // what do i need to do here?
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found\n");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An I/O exception has occured\n");
        } finally {
                if (br != null)
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("File is already closed");
                }
            }
```

Any thoughts?

EDIT: All students in the file have passed the according subjects.

Comment: make Student class, parse for each with `br.readLine().strip().split(",")`

Comment: How do you determine whether the student has passed or not? Based on what criteria?

Comment: @RavindraRanwala The csv files contains only students that have passed. Thus their grade is >= 5

Comment: You haven't attempted anything at all, making this another "do my homework for me" type of question. I give you a hint though, use a dictionary to do the group by counting.

Comment: First, learn how to read a CSV using an API. Then, once you have that, you will be able to create a POJO to "group" your results by student.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it easily using Java8 like so,

```
Pattern comma = Pattern.compile(",");
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("C:\\data\\sample.txt"))) {
    Map<Integer, Long> numberOfLessonsPassed = stream.skip(1).map(l -> comma.split(l))
            .map(s -> new Student(Integer.valueOf(s[0]), s[1], Integer.valueOf(s[2])))
            .filter(s -> s.getGrade() >= 5)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getId, Collectors.counting()));
    System.out.println(numberOfLessonsPassed);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

First read the file, skipping the header line. Then split each line using a `,` regex. After that map each splitted line into a `Student` object. Filter out any students whose `grade < 5`. Finally group the remaining students by their `Id` while counting the number of students in each group.

The `Student` model class should look like this.

```
public class Student {
    private final int id;
    private final String subjectId;
    private final int grade;

    public Student(int id, String subjectId, int grade) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.subjectId = subjectId;
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getSubjectId() {
        return subjectId;
    }

    public int getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

}
```

I  have used a `.txt` file assuming you will be able to port this to a `.csv` file.

Comment: The problem with this solution is with my Locale, the decimal character is the comma ;)

Comment: So i'm mapping every student according to their ID and then for each subject they have passed i add a new record in the map? Seems a little complex for an assignment that is supposed to help a student understand the basic principles of java. Would an ArrayList work? For example i add every student inside the arraylist and then according to their ID, i save their info in a new arraylist and count the number of elements inside the newly created list.

Comment: Imperative approach would take much code. That's why I used Java8, since this inherently fits in there.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more verbose solution

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

static String csvFile = "your path";


public static void main(String[] args) {
// write your code here
    BufferedReader br = null;
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    //this x value serves as the upper limit for the 
    //number of students you wish to view
    for(int x = 0; x <= 3; x++) {
        try {
            String line;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile.toString()));

            String StudentIDNeeded = Integer.toString(x);
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.substring(0, 1).equals(StudentIDNeeded)) {
                    result.add(line.toString());
                }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found\n");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An I/O exception has occured\n");
        } finally {
            if (br != null)
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("File is already closed");
                }
        }
        System.out.println(result.toString());
    }
}
```

}

This gives a result of

```
[1,A1-102,7, 1,A1-103,6, 1,A1-104,5, 1,A1-108,9, 2,A1-101,5, 3,A1-105,7, 3,A1-101,5]
```

I added in some extra points such as a 3rd student id for testing.

To update the number of students you want to select change the x value within the for loop.

Comment: Can i chop an arraylist in smaller pieces? For example all elements that have ID 1 can be added to a new list, the elements that have ID 2 in another list and so on. It's not efficient to use constant number, my max id is approx 1500.

Comment: I will submit a new submission which addresses this now.

Answer (score 0):

For data organization purposes having one arraylist isn't the best solution. I have appended my last solution to introduce a hashmap that stores arraylists identified by the student ID. Somethings are the same such as the for loop needed the exact number of students.

```
BufferedReader br = null;
    //this is the master HashMap, a datastructure which points to n amount of separate arraylist objects.
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> master = new HashMap<>();

    //x = 3 for demonstration purposes replace the value with the 
    //actual number of students 
    for(int x = 1; x <= 3; x++) {

        try {
            String line;
            ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile.toString()));
            String StudentIDNeeded = Integer.toString(x);

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                if (line.substring(0, 1).equals(StudentIDNeeded)) {
                    result.add(line.substring(2).toString());
                }
            }

            master.put(Integer.toString(x),result);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found\n");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An I/O exception has occured\n");
        } finally {
            if (br != null)
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("File is already closed");
                }
        }

    }

    System.out.println("Hash Size:"+master.size());
    System.out.println("Hash Contents" + master.toString());
}
```

This block of code outputs these two strings

```
Hash Size:3
Hash Contents{1=[A1-102,7, A1-103,6, A1-104,5, A1-108,9], 2=[A1-101,5], 
3=[A1-105,7, A1-101,5]}
```

This solution should scale up to larger sets of data by utilizing many arraylists within a hashmap.